# How to group sorted lat/long with distance condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have data like this  (it's already has been sorted).

```
lat_long
9.999,98.655
9.998,98.647
9.998,98.646
9.998,98.614
9.997,98.655
9.997,98.648
9.997,98.647
9.997,98.646
9.996,98.725
```

I want to group place with condition that the first place(first row) have to be within 500 meters (or 55/1100 in lat/long scale) compared with the next row.For the first row that is further than 500 meters it will be in the second and third group and so on.

I can do this in oraclesql or python .

My expected out put will be like this (but in this example does not match my condition. just for understanding.)

```
lat_long             group      first_lat_long
9.999,98.655          1          9.999,98.655
9.998,98.647          1          9.999,98.655
9.998,98.646          1          9.999,98.655
9.998,98.614          2          9.998,98.614
9.997,98.655          2          9.998,98.614 
9.997,98.648          2          9.998,98.614
9.997,98.647          3          9.997,98.647 
9.997,98.646          3          9.997,98.647 
9.996,98.725          4          9.996,98.725
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Flattened plane model or curve-of-the-earth calculations? Either way, you'll need to calculate the distance of you hypotenuse from point1 to pointx... How do you identify point1? Do you have the lat_long available as separate columns (much easier to work with in Oracle)?

Comment: Harsha Biyani I tried to use python but I stuck in condition in for loop I don't know how to switch to the next place to compared and refer to first place.

Comment: JohnHC point1 is the first row and my calculation based on Flattened plane which you can calculate by using pitagoras